# Beautiful Soup scrape for "Worldwide"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape some Box Office Mojo pages for **Worldwide** box office gross figures using Beautiful Soup.My code below will grab the **Domestic** figures just fine, won't work when I sub in "Worldwide" for "Domestic Total Gross." Maybe because "Worldwide" show's up on the page more than once or something.

Any help on fixing it? I'll past the source code for the two portions as well. Thanks!

**Source code below**

```
<center><table border="0" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#dcdcdc" width="95%"><tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td align="center" colspan="2"><font size="4">Domestic Total Gross: <b>$172,825,435</b></font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td valign="top">Distributor: <b><a href="/studio/chart/?studio=mgm.htm">MGM</a></b></td><td valign="top">Release Date: <b><nobr><a href="/schedule/?view=bydate&release=theatrical&date=1988-12-16&p=.htm">December 16, 1988</a></nobr></b></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td valign="top">Genre: <b>Drama</b></td><td valign="top">Runtime: <b>2 hrs. 13 min.</b></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td valign="top">MPAA Rating: <b>R</b></td><td valign="top">Production Budget: <b>$25 million</b></td></tr></table>  </td>
```

...skip...

```
<tr>
<td width="40%">=&nbsp;<b>Worldwide:</b></td>
<td width="35%" align="right">&nbsp;<b>$354,825,435</b></td>
<td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

**Python code below**

```
BOG_titles = ['=RainMan.htm']
def get_movie_value(soup, field_name):
obj = soup.find(text = re.compile(field_name))
if not obj:
    return "Nothing"
next_sibling = obj.findNextSibling()
if next_sibling:
    return next_sibling.text
else:
    return "Still Nothing"

BOG_data = []
for x in BOG_titles:
y = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id' + x
page = urllib2.urlopen(y)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
m = get_movie_value(soup, "Worldwide")
title_string = soup.find('title').text
title = title_string.split('(')[0].strip()
BOG_data.append([title,m])
```

Comment: What exact info do you want?

Comment: I want Worldwide box office gross figures for a variety of films, as listed on Box Office Mojo pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table inside the `div.mp_box`  structure to get what you want:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [2]: import requests
In [3]: r = requests.get("http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=rainman.htm").content

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")

In [5]: table = soup.select_one("div.mp_box table")

In [6]: print(table)
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="40%"><b>Domestic:</b></td>
<td align="right" width="35%"> <b>$172,825,435</b></td>
<td align="right" width="25%">   <b>48.7%</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%">+ <a href="/movies/?page=intl&amp;id=rainman.htm">Foreign:</a></td>
<td align="right" width="35%"> $182,000,000</td>
<td align="right" width="25%">   51.3%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" width="100%"><hr/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%">= <b>Worldwide:</b></td>
<td align="right" width="35%"> <b>$354,825,435</b></td>
<td width="25%"> </td>
</tr>
</table>

In [7]: rows = table.select("tr")

In [8]: rows[0].select_one("td + td").text
Out[8]: u'\xa0$172,825,435'

In [9]: rows[1].select_one("td + td").text
Out[9]: u'\xa0$182,000,000'

In [10]: rows[-1].select_one("td + td").text
Out[10]: u'\xa0$354,825,435'
```

To use the text without specifying the row:

```
In [27]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")

In [28]: table = soup.select_one("div.mp_box table")

In [29]: print(table.find("b",  text="Domestic:").find_next("td").text)
 $172,825,435

In [30]: print(table.find("b",  text="Worldwide:").find_next("td").text)
 $354,825,435

 In [31]: print(table.find("a",  text="Foreign:").find_next("td").text)
 $182,000,000
```

Comment: Thanks. So I just installed lxml to try this, but still an error says I don't have a tree parser with lxml features. Looking through posts on this...

Comment: You can just use the standard parser, I just used lxml out of habit. You just need the latter select if you just want the worldwide

Comment: How would I alter your code to use a different parser? Sorry never used them, so need to install one (and can't get lxml working oddly).

Comment: Change `soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")`.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I'm using `http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=rainman.htm` along with the code you suggested above, except `soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")`

Comment: What version of beautifulsoup? Also are you sure urllib2 is giving you what you expect?